# JSON::XS "Usage" croak

Tags: json, perl, perl-module

I can't seem to use `JSON::XS`'s OO interface properly. The following croaks with an error I can't track down:

```
use JSON::XS;
my $array = ['foo', 'bar'];

my $coder = JSON::XS->new->utf8->pretty;
print $coder->encode_json($array);
```

This croaks with the following: `Usage: JSON::XS::encode_json(scalar) at test.pl line 5.` I have been combing through the code for `JSON::XS` and I can't find a "Usage:" warning anywhere. My usage seems to be pretty well matched with the examples in the documentation. Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`JSON::XS`](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON%3a%3aXS) has two interfaces: functional and OO.

- In the functional interface, the function name is `encode_json`.
- In the OO interface, the method is simply `encode`, not `encode_json`.

Both of the following two snippets work:

```
# Functional                  | # OO
------------------------------+-----------------------------------------
                              | 
use JSON::XS;                 | use JSON::XS;
my $array = ['foo', 'bar'];   | my $array = [ 'foo', 'bar' ];
                              |
print encode_json($array);    | my $coder = JSON::XS->new->utf8->pretty;
                              | print $coder->encode($array);
                              |
# ["foo","bar"]               | # [
                              | #    "foo",
                              | #    "bar"
                              | # ]
```

Comment: The OO version is confused between `@array` and `$array` (and assigns an array reference to `@array`)

Comment: @Borodin : Well spotted... fixed

Comment: Thanks for answering this! I wonder why the author didn't just use one method name and check if the first argument was a JSON::XS reference...